# Dojocharts - bar chart using triangles instead of bars

Tags: javascript, charts, dojo, dojox.charting

I'm generating to create a chart in dojocharts that is like a bar chart but uses triangles instead of rectangle bars (ie the longer the triangle the bigger the value it represents).I have creating a traingular chart using an area chart by some ugly code.Here my X-axis label name not showing correctly.So if adjust it with 0 values ,then it shows all name of x-axis values. I was wondering if something closer to what I need exists so I don't have to plot these fake 0  values.I need this triangle shape chart instead of bar.Here is my jsfiddle link [http://jsfiddle.net/kairi/UxNZD/].

Here is my code for triangle chart...

```
     require(["dojox/charting/Chart", "dojox/charting/themes/Claro",   "dojox/lang/functional/object", "dijit/registry",
  "dojo/on", "dojo/dom", "dojo/_base/event", "dojo/parser",  "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",
   "dojox/charting/plot2d/Areas", "dojox/charting/plot2d/Grid", "dojo/domReady!"],
   function( Chart, Claro, on, dom, baseEvent, parser) {
    // Create the base chart
    chart = new Chart("chart");
    chart.setTheme(Claro);
   chart.addAxis("x", {
fixLower: "major", natural: true, stroke: "grey",
majorTick: {stroke: "black", length: 4},
minorTick: {stroke: "gray", length: 2},
labels: [{"value":1,"text":"Green<br>View"},{"value":2,"text":"Purple"},{"value":3,"text":"Time<br>Residency"},{"value":4,"text":"Marina<br>Apartments"},{"value":5,"text":"Ivory"},{"value":6,"text":"Callidora"},{"value":7,"text":"Almeria"},{"value":8,"text":"Vastus"},{"value":20,"text":"Canary<br>Greens"},{"value":10,"text":"Terra"}],
                     font: "normal normal bold 13px Myriad Pro Light", 
                      fontColor: "black"
 });

    chart.addAxis("y", {
 vertical: true, min: 0, max: 100,
 majorTickStep:10, minorTickStep: 1, stroke: "grey",
 majorTick: {stroke: "black", length: 4},
 minorTick: {stroke: "gray", length: 2}
  });

     chart.addPlot("default", {type: "Areas",gap:10,
      lines:true,
      areas: true,
       // markers: true,
        labels: true,
        labelStyle:"inside",
        fontColor: "black"});

   chart.addSeries("Series A",
   [0,55.5,0,0,37.5,0,0,40,0,0,90,0,0,42.5,0,0,62,0,0,82.5,0,0,72,0,0,42.5,0,0,50,0]
  );      
    chart.render();
    parser.parse();

  });
```

I am not find any solution in dojo.So tell me how is it possible.
Appreciate any help ..

Comment: Is this the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24712219/dojochart-issues-how-can-i-convert-shape-of-bar-chart-into-triangel-chart ?

Comment: @DimitriM I am sorry, But i don't have an idea about this.Do you have solution for this question. I would be appreciated.

Comment: @Christophe  Do you have solution for this question

Comment: @Eugene Lazutkin Do you have solution for this question ?

Comment: They're not going to be notified if you mention them just like this (I think). Besides that, they're not that active on SO (at least not in the Dojo tag).

Comment: @DimitriM kindly suggest me solution for this question ?

Comment: I have no experience with the dojo charting library and I don't know if it's possible either. I suppose it's not going to be possible out of the box.